# Why does the while cycle skips and only reads the first line?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

```
$ ls
testscript.sh  testservers.txt
$ cat testservers.txt 
serverA IMM 10.2.3.4    USERID  PASSW0RD
serverB IMM 10.2.3.5    USERID  PASSW0RD
$ 
$ 
$ cat testscript.sh 
#!/bin/bash

# test them..
egrep -vi '^#|^$' testservers.txt | while read ONELINE; do
    # variables..
    SERVER=`echo "$ONELINE" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {print $1}'`
    RSATYPE=`echo "$ONELINE" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {print $2}'`
    IP=`echo "$ONELINE" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {print $3}'`
    USER=`echo "$ONELINE" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {print $4}'`
    PWD=`echo "$ONELINE" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {print $5}'`

if [ "$RSATYPE" = "IMM" ]; then
    # main testing part for IMM
        timeout 5 tsocks nc -z -w 3 "${IP}" 80 > /dev/null 2>&1; if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; 
            then WEBINTOK="true"
            else WEBINTOK="false"
            fi

        IMMSSH=`(timeout 5 tsocks sshpass -p "${PWD}" ssh -l "${USER}" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "${IP}" exit)`
        if echo "${IMMSSH}" | grep -q "tty name check failed"; then 
            ${WEBINTOK} && echo -e "${SERVER} ${USER} - OK" || echo -e "${SERVER} ${USER} - ERROR"
        else 
            ${WEBINTOK} && echo -e "${SERVER} ${USER} - ERROR" || echo -e "${SERVER} ${USER} - ERROR"
        fi
fi

done
$ 
$ bash testscript.sh 
serverA USERID - OK
$
```

**Our quesiton**: why does the script only reads the first line?? It suppose to read all the lines in the testservers.txt ..

UPDATE: the testservers.txt has correct TAB's, I don't really think that is the problem :\

```
$ cat -vte testservers.txt
serverA^IIMM^I10.2.3.4^IUSERID^IPASSW0RD$
serverB^IIMM^I10.2.3.5^IUSERID^IPASSW0RD$
$
```

Comment: My 2 cents: You are not using TAB character in the testservers.txt and then the IF fails. Btw, is it your own code? Haven't you tried to add some debug `echo`?

Comment: You don't need to set the `FS` in `awk` anyway. It defaults to whitespace (that includes a space and a `\t`).

Comment: How about:`...echo "$ONELINE" | read SERVER RSATYPE IP USER PWD...`? It doesn't solve your immediate problem, but it definitely makes for more readable code.

Comment: Can you indent the outer if properly.

Comment: Just a thought. Is it possible you have `-e` set and the script exits prematurely due to an error?

Comment: Probably `nc` eats the whole of the standard input. (your code is awful btw).

Comment: I have just run it with the tsocks stuff removed and it outputs 2 lines, I also think there is something making the script exit early.

Comment: Can you indent the first inner if. I just noticed it that is why I did not mention if in my first comment.

Comment: I think that using `` is considered bad form these days, it is better to use `$()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got:

```
egrep... | while read ...; do
    ...
    ... ssh $IP exit...
    ...
  done
```

`ssh` connects to the remote host and runs the remote command and sends it what it reads from its stdin (unless passed the `-n` option)

In that case, `ssh`'s stdin is the pipe from `egrep`, the same pipe `read` is reading from.

So, it will typically read all the output of `egrep` and send it to the `exit` command on `$IP` (the remote shell or `exit` doesn't read it, but `ssh` will have read it).

`nc` is another command that reads its stdin to send over the connection it establishes, but not when passed the `-z` option as you do here.

To avoid the problem, use the `-n` option to `ssh` or redirect `ssh`'s stdin from `/dev/null` (`ssh < /dev/null...`).

Answer (score 2):

Stéphane has the right answer. I'm commenting about style mostly.

To reduce the work you have to do reading variables, instead of

```
while read ONELINE; do
    # variables..
    SERVER=`echo "$ONELINE" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {print $1}'`
    RSATYPE=`echo "$ONELINE" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {print $2}'`
    IP=`echo "$ONELINE" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {print $3}'`
    USER=`echo "$ONELINE" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {print $4}'`
    PWD=`echo "$ONELINE" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {print $5}'`
    # ...
```

do this

```
while IFS=$'\t' read SERVER RSATYPE IP USER PWD; do
    # ...
```

Instead of writing

```
some command 
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    do_this
else
    do_that
fi
```

write

```
if some command; then
    do_this
else
    do_that
fi
```

Since this is specifcally a bash script, instead of

```
echo "${IMMSSH}" | grep -q "tty name check failed"
```

do

```
grep -q "tty name check failed" <<<"${IMMSSH}"
```

Also, get out of the habit of using ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES: one day you'll use `PATH` and then wonder why your script is broken when you can't find any external commands.

Comment: more `[[ $IMMSSH = *"tty name check failed"* ]]` or POSIXly: `case $IMMSSH in (*"tty name check failed"*) ...;; esac`