# Bash: How to skip jammed function?

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash

function thous {
    numfmt --g $1 | sed 's/,/./g;s/@//g'
}

aa="1,235"
bb="5,22"
cc=$(echo "$aa + $bb" | bc)

#1
echo $aa
#2
echo $bb
#3
echo $(thous "$cc")
#4
echo "SKIP"

exit
```

What shown

```
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
1,235
5,22
```

What I want

```
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
1,235
5,22
(some error or nothing at all)
SKIP
```

If you try to compile this bash shell code, you will got stuck on #3. So, How to tell the terminal, to ignore whatever that cannot be processed and just go on the next process?

Please do tell me if the question is unclear, Thank you

Comment: It's not clear what that `thous` is trying to do. Thousand separators and decimal radix characters are locale dependant. What is `s/,/./g` meant to do? Change the decimal radix from `,` to `.`? Change the thousand separator from `,` to `.`? Why removing the `@`s. Where would they come from?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas sorry for late reply, normally when I have thousand separator in my shell script, I usually put `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` on top of the script. I'm using numfmt to format the thousand separator, somehow my bash doesn't accept any other locale other than US, so, in order to change the number from 1,000.00 to my actual local thousand separator which is 1.000,00, that's what the `sed` does.

Comment: Swapping `,` and `.` would be done with `tr ,. .,`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ah! I learned something useful again, what a useful command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When your script stops, it’s actually `numfmt` waiting for input — press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> and it will continue.

This happens because `numfmt` formats its standard input if it’s not given any non-option arguments, and `$cc` is empty.

A general technique to avoid having `numfmt` block like this, it to make it read from `/dev/null`:

```
numfmt --g $1 < /dev/null | sed 's/,/./g;s/@//g'
```

See [Why is this while loop exiting after the first iteration?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/682748/86440) for another example where this technique is useful.

However a better approach in your specific case would be [to quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/86440); then `numfmt` will always have an argument, even if `$1` is empty:

```
numfmt --g "$1" | sed 's/,/./g;s/@//g'
```

You should also avoid option abbreviations in scripts; `--g` is liable to break if a future version of `numfmt` introduces another long option starting with “g”. While we’re at it, be sure to separate options from arguments with `--` (otherwise `numfmt` balks at negative values):

```
numfmt --grouping -- "$1" | sed 's/,/./g;s/@//g'
```

The script will then run to completion without pause. Once you fix the `$cc` calculation it will output the expected result; in the mean time, with the `"$1"` variant you’ll see

```
numfmt: invalid number: ‘’
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer, so `< /dev/null` is the key, I'll note it. is it applicable only on numfmt, or it will also work on another?

Comment: It will work with any command which attempts to read from its standard output (and you don’t want it to).

Comment: @StephenKitt I see that you added more detail to the answer, I'm very appreciate that, I'll keep those method in mind and note it. Thank you