# bash script suddenly exiting with set -e without error

Tags: shell-script

The script is a bit sensitive, so I'll hide some details, but the script runs up to the > mark

```
    auth="$(mariadb -N -h $DBHOST -P $DBPORT $DBNAME -e "SELECT ..... -u $DBUSER -p$DBPASS)"
    > ssh -i /root/.ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key -oStrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new "IP" "do $auth"
    
    export GFS="IPS"
    for ip2 in $GFS; do ufw allow from $ip2; done
    for ip2 in $GFS; do ssh -i /root/.ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key -oStrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new -n "$ip2" "ufw allow from $MYIP"; done
...
```

The ssh command executes without error, then script just stops. Even with bash -x I can't see anything wrong.

It's even weirder because this only happens in the full script, if I create a test script with just the needed variables, and the same code, it runs fine.

How to debug this?

Comment: What shell is running your script?   Are "IP" and "IPS" hidden details?

Comment: GFS hasn't been set readonly earlier in the script?

Comment: No GFS hasn't been set read-only, the IPS and IPS are my hidden ips separated by space

Comment: Does the second line actually start with `>`, redirecting the `-i` command into a file called `ssh`?

Comment: As written, your code hardly makes any sense.

Comment: how to debug: try with `set -e` disabled and check the exit status of the `ssh`, e.g. `echo "ssh exited with status $?"` on the next line. Or if you need to keep `set -e` on, change it to `ssh ... | true` (with the pipe), and check `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` instead of `$?` on the next line (in Bash only, though). I'm not sure if there's something missing, but it looks like you're passing `"do $auth"` as the command for `ssh` to run on the remote, and that's likely to give a syntax error on the remote, if there's a regular shell there. Where your errors go, well, that I can't know.

Comment: anyway, if it stops on the `ssh` line, then the `for` loops after it are rather irrelevant for the issue, no? Creating a script with only the relevant parts is the right approach, but if the problem doesn't appear with such a reduced script, ...well, then it _didn't_ contain all the relevant parts and you need to try something else. Start by removing everything after the part where it stops to reduce distractions. Then look at what the failing command relies on, and remove everything else. If it stops failing, you removed something that was important to issue.

Comment: trial by error can help: remove some part that _looks_ like it shouldn't matter, if the behaviour changed, it _did_ matter, and you need to put it back and look closer. Repeat. The issue here wrt. the SE question is that we here have absolutely no idea what your script does, so we can't know if something you left out is important. And it's _not_ fun to try to guess possible reasons just to find out there was actually something really simple we didn't get to see (and you didn't notice).

Comment: Does it work if you [use ssh -n](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/150128/22222)?

Comment: I found it does work If I add -n to ssh. Should I delete the question?

Comment: No, it's better that you add an answer to your own question with the solution, preferably after you've read about it and understood how it fixed your problem, and mark your own answer as "accepted", so people that encounter the same issue in the future could find a clear explanation here. Thanks!